# ModelForm Django 1.11 overwrite error messages

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

How can I overwrite the default form error messages in ModelForm in Django 1.11, Such as 'Enter a valid value.' or something like that?

In the official documentation has this example, but it does not show how to override other types of error messages than this one.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'unique_together': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique.",
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `NON_FIELD_ERRORS` and field-related errors. You can override field-related ones in the following way:
(from the [Overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) article):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
        error_messages = {
            'name': {
                'max_length': _("This writer's name is too long."),
            },
        }
```

Comment: seems to be very interesting, I'll take a look and tell you if it worked.